# CSS hover events not being picked up on submenu within a submenu

Tags: html, css

On a site I'm working on, I have a submenu within a submenu. The level-2 submenu is taller than the parent level-1 submenu. I'm using css to basically say, if i'm hovering over the parent list item of the level-1 submenu, or the level-1 submenu itself, the level-1 submenu is visible, and i'm repeating the same thing for the level-2 submenu. But when the mouse leaves the bounds of the level-1 submenu, it seems like pointer events on the level-2 item are not being picked up anymore.

I understand this is really confusing to understand but you can see it in action on this sloppily-and-quickly-thrown-together staging site (I know it's not in its best state, please be patient for the styling to appear): http://kachinahouse.newbird.co/

Hover over All Categories, Native American Artifacts, and try to select a submenu item a bit down the list. The entire menu disappears as if hover events aren't being recieved as soon as you leave the bounds of the level-1 submenu.

- In safari, hover events on level-2 don't even seem to be registered.
- In chrome, level-2 hover events disappear when the mouse leaves the bounds of level-1
- In firefox, everything works as expected and the submenus stay open as long as I'm hovering over them.

Should be noted that I am not using display:none to hide the submenu items before their appearance, I'm using a combination of opacity, visibility and pointer-events:none so that I can use smooth fading transitions. I mention this because I'm wondering if my pointer-events might be mucking things up somehow...? I don't see how though.

Simplified example of my css:

```
.sub-menu-level-1 {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

li:hover > .sub-menu-level-1,
li > .sub-menu-level-1:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

Am i doing something dumb, or is this some kind of browser issue?

I'd like to avoid using Javascript if possible, I just feel like it shouldn't be needed for something like this...

I have checked everywhere for pointer-events:none, overflow properties, z-index issues, etc...

Here's a copy and paste of the actual CSS/HTML

```
.menu-wrapper {
  background-color: @color-orange;
  color: @color-white;
  position: relative;

  .all-categories {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    order: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: transform, opacity, visibility;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: @color-white;
    padding: 25px 45px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: @color-black;

    .toggle-nav > ul {
      columns: 4;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      max-height: 450px;

      li {
        padding-right: 20px;
        break-inside: avoid;

        a {
          line-height: 1.2;
          display: block;
          padding: 20px 0;
        }

        .sub-menu {
          left: calc(~'100% - 20px');
          top: 0;
          border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
          padding: 20px 30px;
          color: #666666;

          li {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 0;

            a {
              padding: 10px 0;
            }
          }
        }

        &.menu-item-has-children {
          &::after {
            display: none;
          }

          > a::after {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 10px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 6px solid #B2B2B2;
            border-top: 4px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .see-all-categories {
    order: 1;
    color: @color-white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: @font-main;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 10px 30px 0;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid @color-white;
      border-right: 2px solid @color-white;
      transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 50%;
    }

    &:hover + .all-categories,
    + .all-categories:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      pointer-events: initial;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="all-categories">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls">Kachina Dolls</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/antique-native-american-hopi-katsinam">Antique Native American Hopi Katsinam</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/hopi-full-figure-katsinam">Hopi Full Figure Katsinam</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/hopi-katsinam-sculptures">Hopi Katsinam Sculptures</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/hopi-miniature-katsinam">Hopi Miniature Katsinam</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/hopi-old-style-katsinam">Hopi Old Style Katsinam</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/kachinas-on-sale">Kachina and Katsina Dolls on SALE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/navajo-kachinas">Navajo Kachinas</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-katsina-and-kachina-dolls/new-acquisitions">New Acquisitions at Kachina House</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/native-american-jewelry">Native American Jewelry</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/native-american-jewelry/native-american-necklaces">Native American Necklaces</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-jewelry/native-american-bracelets">Native American Bracelets </a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-jewelry/native-american-rings">Native American Rings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-jewelry/native-american-earrings">Native American Earrings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-jewelry/native-american-buckle">Native American Buckles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/native-american-artifacts">Native American Artificats</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/artifacts-on-sale">Artifacts On Sale</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/bows">Native American Bows</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/breastplates-and-chokers">Breastplates and Chokers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/cradleboards">Cradleboards</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/dreamcatchers-and-medicine-wheels">Dreamcatchers and Medicine Wheels</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/warbonnets">Warbonnets</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/drums-and-flutes">Drums and Flutes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/knives">Knives</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/hatchets-and-tomahawks">Hatchets and Tomahawks</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/lances-and-arrows">Lances and Arrows</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/dance-sticks-and-trail-markers">Dance Sticks and Trail Markers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/medicine-bags-pouches-and-handbags">Medicine Bags, Pouches and Handbags</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/pipes">Pipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/prayer-fans">Prayer Fans</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/quivers">Quivers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/rattles">Rattles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artifacts/shields">Shields</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/native-american-pottery">Native American Pottery</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/horsehair-pottery">Horsehair Pottery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/navajo-etched-pottery">Navajo Etched Pottery</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
          <a href="/native-american-pottery/specialty-pottery">Specialty Pottery</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/specialty-pottery/specialty-handbuilt-pottery">Specialty Hand-Coiled Clay Pottery</a></li>
            <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/specialty-pottery/specialty-ceramic-pottery">Specialty Slip-Poured Ceramic Pottery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/specialty-pottery/specialty-handbuilt-pottery">Specialty Hand-Coiled Clay Pottery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/specialty-pottery/specialty-ceramic-pottery">Specialty Slip-Poured Ceramic Pottery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/sale-pottery">SALE-Pottery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/storytellers">Native American Storyteller Figurines</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-pottery/wedding-vases">Wedding Vases</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/native-american-zuni-fetishes">Zuni Fetishes</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-baskets">Native American Baskets</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="/native-american-artists">Native American Artists</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/dwight-armstrong">Dwight Armstrong</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/marc-bilagody">Marc Bilagody</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/cecil-calnimptewa-jr">Cecil Calnimptewa Jr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/larson-chapella">Larson Chapella</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/manuel-chavarria-jr">Manuel Chavarria Jr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/raymond-chee">Raymond Chee</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/norman-cuch">Norman Cuch</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/jason-curley">Jason Curley</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/randolph-david">Randolph David</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/neil-david-sr">Neil David Sr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/shawn-deel">Shawn Deel</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/dominic-east">Dominic East</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/john-fredericks">John Fredericks</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/joe-gash">Joe Gash</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/dorleen-gashweseoma">Dorleen Gashweseoma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/ros-george">Ros George</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/gloria-gorman">Gloria Gorman</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/richard-gorman">Richard Gorman</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/andrew-grover">Andrew Grover</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/cimmaron-grover">Cimmaron Grover</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/arthur-holmes-jr">Arthur Holmes Jr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/brian-holmes">Brian Holmes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/darian-honahnie">Darian Honahnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/troy-honahnie">Troy Honahnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/philbert-honanie">Philbert Honanie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/lester-honanveama">Lester Honanveama</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/marlin-honhongva">Marlin Honhongva</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/kevin-honyouti">Kevin Honyouti</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/lauren-honyouti">Lauren Honyouti</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/ronald-honyouti-ron-honyouti">Ronald Honyouti (Ron Honyouti)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/aaron-honyumptewa">Aaron Honyumptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/orlan-honyumptewa">Orlan Honyumptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/frankie-howard">Frankie Howard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/milton-howard">Milton Howard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/bryson-huma">Bryson Huma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/allen-joshevama">Allen Joshveama</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/brendon-kayquoptewa">Brendon Kayquoptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/d-armon-kootswatewa">D'Armon Kootswatewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/renford-koruh">Renford Koruh</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/gene-lalo">Gene Lalo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/raynard-lalo">Raynard Lalo</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/ila-lou-lomawaima">Ila Lou Lomawaima</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/virgil-long">Virgil Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/sean-macias">Sean Macias</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/kevin-masawiestewa">Kevin Masawiestewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/larry-melendez">Larry Melendez</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/cecil-miles">Cecil Miles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/aldrick-mooya">Aldrick Mooya</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/willard-mowa">Willard Mowa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/augustine-mowa-iii">Augustine Mowa III</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/augustine-mowa-jr">Augustine Mowa Jr</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/henry-naha">Henry Naha</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/wayland-namingha">Wayland Namingha</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/hyram-namoki">Hyram Namoki</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/lawrence-namoki">Lawrence Namoki</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/adrian-nasafotie">Adrian Nasafotie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/larin-nasafotie">Larin Nasafotie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/bryan-nasetoynewa">Bryan Nasetoynewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/fawn-navasie">Fawn Navasie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/brad-panteah">Brad Panteah</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/calvin-pavatea">Calvin Pavatea</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/ted-pavatea">Ted Pavatea</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/delmar-polacca">Delmar Polacca</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/clarina-poleahla">Clarina Poleahla</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/ryon-polequaptewa">Ryon Polequaptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/tayron-polequaptewa">Tayron Polequaptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/jerel-quamahongnewa">Jerel Quamahongnewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/coolidge-roy-jr">Coolidge Roy Jr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/eric-roy">Eric Roy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/silas-roy">Silas Roy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/alex-sanchez">Alex Sanchez</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/kevin-sekakuku">Kevin Sekakuku</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/shawn-sekaquaptewa">Shawn Sekaquaptewa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/susan-shatreau-janisky">Susan Shatreau-Janisky</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/bennett-sockyma">Bennett Sockyma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/donald-sockyma">Donald Sockyma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/lee-sockyma">Lee Sockyma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/quinston-taylor">Quinston Taylor</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/leander-tenakhongva">Leander Tenakhongva</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/robert-tenorio">Robert Tenorio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/wilfred-tewawina-jr">Wilfred Tewawina Jr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/jonah-thompson">Jonah Thompson</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/carlton-timms">Carlton Timms</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/conrad-torivio">Conrad Torivio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/fermin-torivio">Fermin Torivio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/abeita-torres">Abeita Torres</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/jacob-n-warner">Jacob N. Warner</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/johnny-wester-iii">Johnny Wester III</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/alexander-youvella-sr">Alexander Youvella Sr.</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/darrell-youvella">Darrell Youvella</a></li>
        <li><a href="/native-american-artists/preston-youvella">Preston Youvella</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/gourd-art-by-robert-rivera">Native American Gourd Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-showpieces">Native American Showpieces</a></li>
    <li><a href="/casas-grandes-paquime-renaissance-pottery-from-mata-ortiz">Casas Grandes/Paquime Renaissance Pottery from Mata Ortiz</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-navajo-rugs">Native American Navajo Rugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/navajo-art">Navajo Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-painted-hides-and-paintings">Native American Painted Hides and Paintings</a></li>
    <li><a href="/jewelry-keepsake-boxes">Native American Jewelry Keepsake Boxes</a></li>
    <li><a href="/wild-north-american-animal-skulls">Wild North American Animal Skulls</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-made-mini-packs-of-10">Native American Made Mini-Packs of 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sale-items">Sale Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="/native-american-christmas-items">Native American Christmas Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="/kachina-house-shirts">Kachina House Shirts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/books-for-sale">Books for Sale</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gift-certificates">Gift Certificates</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect that when I am hovering over an .item, .item:hover styling should be active..... right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the menu CSS from scratch basically, and it is working now (even with using `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`). I'm not 100% on what the issue was, but I am about 86.239% sure that it was related to the level-1 submenu having the `columns` property, and `break-inside: avoid` on its child menu items. The level-2 submenus were children of the level-1 menu items, so I'm guessing the `break-inside` was affecting those level-2 submenus as well, even though they were position absolute and appeared fine visually. I found a way to keep the same layout using flexbox instead of css columns, and it is working much better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overcomplicating your styles, specially with the `pointer-events` styles and whatnot. If all the elements in your menus and submenus are links/hoverable items, you should not be removing the `pointer-events` or their individual visibility, and instead make the parent container invisible.

Additionally, since you're styling with SCSS, you're nesting your `.sub-menu` inside a path that makes the `.sub-menu` quite a specific CSS rule. Your CSS reads like so:

```
.menu-wrapper .all-categories .toggle-nav > ul li a .submenu {
    left: calc(~'100% - 20px');
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    color: #666666;
}
```

As a standard, you should avoid nesting down to 5 levels, for simplicity's sake.

In regards to your `:hover` problem, I don't see the `.sub-menu` hover styles, or the `.see-all-categories` element.

Try simplifying your example and post a snippet of your code replicating the problem so it's a little bit clearer to debug. Who knows, you might even find the issue yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I usually try to keep things very clean but I agree things kinda got crazy here. Also on a real tight schedule so sorry if some stuff got left out. I'll spend some time and try to simplify it and make sure all the right stuff is included. As for the pointer-events though... Isn't that a necessity? Because if the elements are just invisible, users will still be able to accidentally click on the links in the submenus when the menus aren't even visible to them.

Comment: If you use `display: none` on the parent element, your submenu will be *invisible*, *unclickable* and *unfocusable*. No need to use `visibility` instead. If you just make it invisible by using `visibility: none`, the space for the element will still be reserved. If you only use `opacity`, the element will still be focusable. Check this out: https://fuzzbomb.github.io/accessibility-demos/visually-hidden-focus-test.html

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I guess i was expecting `visibility: hidden` to work like opacity, but in hindsight that would make it a little redundant i guess. That's helpful... I'll try messing around with that and see where it gets me.